# TypeORM @OneToMany doesn't appear to try and execute when called

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typegraphql

I have looked at the examples and as far as i can tell i followed them to the letter... my @ManyToOne join runs in query as expected but the @OneToMany doesn't seem to fire when included in my graphql playground call.. all other data for User comes back as expected with the exception of the device info

This is in my User.ts entity:

```
@Field(type => [Devices], { nullable: true })
@OneToMany(() => Devices, devices => devices.user)
devices: Devices[];
```

This is the entry in my Devices.ts Entity:

```
  Field(type => User)
  @ManyToOne(type => User, { lazy: true })
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "userId", referencedColumnName: "userId" }])
  user: User;
```

Before i added the nullable: true above i was just getting an error saying can't return null for required blah blah... I thought maybe i had a device with no user but that was not the case.. In the terminal query output it only queries the user table and makes no attempt at getting devices...

My graphql call is super simple but just returns nulls for all devices:

```
{
  users{
    name
    phone
    devices{
      deviceId
    }
  }
}
```

My @ManyToOne also returned nulls for user until i set { lazy: true } and i am not sure why for that either.. There is obviously no setting like that for @OneToMany.. I am a sequelize, javascript baby and this is my first crack at TypeORM so any help would be appreciated. Or if there is relevant code i have not put in, let me know and i'll do it up.. Cheers in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting.... I barely saw an example of this anywhere but I ended up adding
`{ lazy: true }` to the `@OneToMany` calls as well and they now work. I didn't realize that was an option

```
@Field(type => [Devices], { nullable: true,  })
@OneToMany(() => Devices, devices => devices.user, { lazy: true })
devices: Devices[];
```

Comment: This can be a bit confusing unless you've learned the [TypeORM documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/eager-and-lazy-relations.md) and some of the project issues by heart. Marking the relation as lazy is one way to go, but you could as well use the query builder pattern, or `find` attributes as suggested in [this stellar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63811529/1285763). I believe specifying the relation where the query is issued would be idiomatic `TypeORM` code.

Comment: You can use lazy field to automatic resolve the relations (nested fields) on demand:
https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/tree/master/examples/typeorm-lazy-relations
Or just write the field resolvers manually, e.g. when you need to query the db using some parameter (field arg):
https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/tree/master/examples/typeorm-basic-usage